# i want to post data through rest api using flutter with Forget password

Tags: java, database, flutter, api, dart

The api response is:status code 200 but it shown unexpected end of json input.
**This is my controller code:**

```
static Future<UserLogin> ForgetPassword(String email) async {
        final http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'http://192.168.0.134:8080/AtdochubJ-3/send-otp?email=${email}'),   
        );           
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
          return UserLogin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
               } else {      
          print(response.body);
          throw Exception('Failed to load UserLogin');
        }
      }
```

Center(
child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
//   final isValidForm = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
//   if (isValidForm) {
final String email = emailController.text;
**This is my code on Forget Password button**

```
           UserLogin res =await LoginController.ForgetPassword(email);

                          if (res != null && email != null) {
                            //  ForgetPassword(email);
                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg: " Email send sucessfully",
                                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 12.0);
                          }
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  ResetPassword()));
                        },
                        // },
                        child: const Text("Send OTP"),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
                      )),
```

Comment: Share more code snippet. What's the response returned from API?

Comment: What the `print('Response body: ${response.body}');` prints to console ? Anyway, you got 200 but failing then...  It seems `fromJson`

Comment: print('Response body: ${response.body}');  it gives only status code 200  i was sending request only object not a string. so my response body is blank and that time it shows status code  and give error unexpected end of json input. Please give me solution.

Comment: @SwatiSuryawanshi Got solution? If not share the complete response getting from your API